# How long does a SE site stay in public beta?

Tags: discussion

I just had a look at the [stats at Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla), and compared the progress with other beta sites. But what is needed to get a site out of beta stage?

I was surprised to see several pages with more than 1000 days in beta, and excellent stats. Why are they still in Beta? (Code Review has 32.9 questions/day, 43000 + users, and 23000+ visits/day, is that what we should aim for?)

*On a side note: Would it be a good idea to ask more questions that might be obvious to experienced Joomla users, but might be useful to new users? That would increase the questions/day ratio, number of questions, and maybe attract more visitors through search engines.*

Comment: In regards to the side note, I would argue for yes with one caveat: if you also know the answer, answer the question right away. This is a great way for you to share your knowledge and help attract interest here. It also keeps from overwhelming the other experts on the site from helping you answer questions you already know. (Not that we won't throw our two cents in if we have more insight into one of your answers!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm Grace Note, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange.

There is no defined length of time that a site stays in public beta. The important thing to understand is that a long beta is not a sign of struggling or problems, at least not from the community side of things. There's nothing wrong with being in public beta.

At raw, we like to see things like sustained and continual *growth* of the traffic towards the site, a userbase that is both interested in sharing knowledge and in managing their peers, and content that the community truly feels proud of making the internet a better place. This is a quick overview but that's a general look at what we look for when choosing what we feel is ready to graduate.

For a site to graduate, though, one of the requirements is that we create a design for them. These designs take some time to make, however, which means we have a decent backlog of designs to go. We have a queue of sites already lined up that we've marked as "Ready to graduate", but until the design is completed, we cannot move forward. We also cannot give any estimates on when the designs will be completed. As such, these, too, stick around in Beta - not out of any fault of the community behind it.

If a site remains in Beta, you can look over the site and think about how your stats are serving your community. Is your traffic growing, is the income of content interesting and useful, are people engaging with each other? If anything seems off, then that is something to take action on, and we on the Community Team at Stack Exchange perform periodic reviews on sites to check their general health and for problem concerns. But it's safe to say that if we don't speak up, and if you as a community find nothing wrong, that things are smooth sailing.

Because of the nature of the queue, there's no functional difference between a site that is "Ready for graduation", and any other public beta site. The default state of a site should generally be interpreted as being on the road to being ready to graduate, if not already at a status that is ready to graduate. Some time down the road, there will be a post from the Design Team that proposes what the new design will be. That will be your cue to be excited for graduation. Until that post comes in, there's no need to worry about your site progress if you can't find anything wrong.

Comment: Hi Grace, a big thanks from me too for clearing this up. Just one more question. I saw a site on Area51 that had been in Public Beta for 300+ days (unless my eyes were playing tricks on me) and I think there were another that had been in this state for even longer. Does that mean that that particular site was below the average required stats to become a proper SE site or the queue is simply that long?

Comment: Queue is simply that long.

Comment: I see that there are many, many questions about Joomla being posted on SE.  Aside from somebody manually telling everyone about the Joomla Beta, is there a way to consider the overall Joomla interest, rather than just those that know that there's a site dedicated to it?

Comment: @GDP They will only ever count traffic on the dedicated site. If the traffic stays on SE, then if anything, it is a sign that this site isn't needed!

Comment: 900+ days and still in Beta. As @GDP points out there are just as many Joomla questions being asked on SO but they are often closed as off-topic, ignored or poorly answered compared to JSE. I can't help thinking if we get out of Beta, then some of those SO questions could be migrated to JSE or maybe they would be asked on JSE in the first place.